# How to auto fill field in a form based on a unique value and values from another form

Tags: javascript, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, autofill

I have a 4 to 5 custom entities with one form each. There is going to be a fluent progress from one form to another e.g, the first entity "Booking Screen" has one form, after filling it the user will move to the next entity and fill its form and the next and so on.

I want the proceeding form to get some information based on the forms filled earlier to be uploaded based on a booking number that will be assigned on the first booking screen.

For example the Booking Screen form has:

First name, last name, booking number (a unique id) and other info...I would like the next form to have the option enter the unique id and then auto-fill the name fields or other information from the first form.

We can either do this by workflow or java script? I would prefer java script as workflows are asynchronous.

How can I do this?

Using the above mentioned libraries and some searching I have come up with this

```
function retrieveRecord(id, odataSetName, successCallback, errorCallback) {

   var context = Xrm.Page.context;

   var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();

   var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";



   //Asynchronous AJAX function to Retrieve a CRM record using OData

   $.ajax({

   type: "GET",

   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

   datatype: "json",

   url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + "(guid'" + id + "')",

   beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {

       //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.            

       XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

   },

   success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

       if (successCallback) {

           successCallback(data.d, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest);

       }

   },

   error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

       if (errorCallback)

           errorCallback(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);

       else

           errorHandler(XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);

   }

});

}
```

But this is only the way to set up the retrieve call right?

I have added *json2* and *jquery 1.4.1.min* library.

Now I have added this on my ONLOAD event of the form that I want to be populated. I want that when I add the booking number on my form (this will go on the ON CHANGE event of the text field I guess) it should retrieve the first name, last name, middle name, SSN#  from the main form i.e booking screen..

How do I do this?

my final code but it is not setting any values on the form fields
function getContactDetails()
{
    var lookUpObjectValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_lookupbookingscree").getValue();
    if ((lookUpObjectValue != null))
    {
        var lookuptextvalue = lookUpObjectValue[0].name;

```
    var lookupid = lookUpObjectValue[0].id;
    //alert(lookupid);


var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();

//The XRM OData end-point
var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";


//var odataSetName = "ContactSet";

var odataSelect = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + "(guid'" + lookupid + "')";

//alert(odataSelect);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: odataSelect,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

         var result_contact= data.d;

        //alert(result_contact.AccountNumber);
                    //replace the fields with the fields on your entity
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_firstname").setValue(result_contact.inmate_firstname);
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("inmate_lastname").setValue(result_contact.inmate_lastname);



    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('OData Select Failed: ' + odataSelect); }
});

}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you've got a good start with your odata query.  Are your firstname and last name fields not getting populated?  Also, as Campey suggests, it probably would result in a cleaner design if you didn't include first name and last name on the first screen, but instead allowed them to select / create a Contact (you could even create a custom Contact form just for this process).  You don't want it to be possible to allow the names to be different between the 4-5 entities that you have.

Comment: Yes they are not getting populated. No I need the names in the booking screen(first screen). They will be read only in the form I want to be auto populated.

Comment: seriously guys I need help why is this not working?!!!
and I have already used the schema name here
setValue(result_contact.inmate_FirstName); and it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that there is a relation between these forms (entities). If so, you can take values from the first screen to the second screen, etc. Go to settings | customizations | customize the system, select your entity, select your relation, for type (dropdownlist) select mappable, select your related entity en finally select mappings. Here you can create mappings between the source fields and the target fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and rethink what you are doing as CRM doesn't really work in a fluent manner between forms.

Instead you would have your main "Booking entity" and then link to Contacts etc (so if you need to enter first name and last name you would click on the Contact lookup and select "New") so you have one base form related to others.

I would also investigate CRM 2013 (Orion) as it has process related forms which may be beneficial.

If you want to pass data between forms you will need a relationship between the forms and then I would use javascript. There is heaps of good samples out there such as this one.
http://crmscape.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/crm-2011-odata-json-and-crm-forms.html

Comment: Thanks Campey and Bokkie for the reply.
I am going to look into your answers and come back with a reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

Take your `odataSelect` Url, and run it in a browser.  Verify that the `inmate_firstname` and `inmate_lastname` are being returned in the response.  If it is, then your problem is with your javascript.  Either it isn't actually getting a response (looks like this isn't the problem, due to your error handling) or, you're accessing the information incorrectly in the response (or the entity doesn't contain a first or last name).  To check for these problems, use F12 debugging in IE to inspect the response data object.

All of that aside, you're URL looks like it's missing the Entity Set Logical Name.  Try this:

```
var odataSetName = "ContactSet";
var odataSelect = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName + "(guid'" + lookupid + "')";
```

Comment: what if odataSetName is not ContactSet?
what odataSetName should be? I am saving a new person in a custom entity not the contact entity that we have in crm.

Comment: It'll always be in the format <EntityLogicalName>Set, but it is case sensitive!  I believe it uses the case of the Schema name, but I'm not sure.  Try taking the OData URL being generated, and pasting it directly into the browser and keep tweaking it until it works.

Comment: http://vt-crm/JailManagementSystem/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_bookingscreen1Set(guid'%7BC9DDE392-3F03-E311-86C8-00155DF5D306%7D')

this is the url that is generated and it gives me an error "Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support. "

Comment: @hkhan, verify that this portion is valid: http://vt-crm/JailManagementSystem/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc.  Then try this: http://vt-crm/JailManagementSystem/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_bookingscreenSet(guid'7BC9DDE392-3F03-E311-86C8-00155DF5D306')  this is assuming that the name of your entity is "new_bookingscreen", not "new_bookingscreen1"

Comment: it is new_bookingscreen1.
i still get the same error. I already tried the above approach of modifying the url :(

Comment: I used the oqeury Data Builder from codeplex and this is my final 
odata query:
var odataSelect = "http://vt-crm/JailManagementSystem/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_bookingscreen1Set" + "(guid'" + lookupid + "')";

I have further added an alert after
 var result_contact= data.d;

and it says undefined. Any help here? Daryl?

Comment: @hkhan - get the URL to return data in the browser first, then make your javascript create the correct URL.